# iFrame loads the page once and then loads continuously in a new tab

Tags: html, ajax, iframe, internet-explorer-7, quirks-mode

I have this weird problem with IE11. I have a series of links:

```
<a href="page1.html" target="iframe_name">Page #1</a>
<a href="page2.html" target="iframe_name">Page #2</a>
<a href="page3.html" target="iframe_name">Page #3</a>
```

And this iFrame:

```
<iframe id="iframe_name" name="iframe_name"></iframe>
```

If a click on a link (any), it will load the page in the iFrame the first time, but it will always open in a new tab/window afterwards. The order of the clicks doesn't matter. Once = iframe, after = new tab.

The links are generated from an AJAX call. They are pure HTML "a" links with no special events bind to them.

I also have this META tag in my HEAD:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, requiresActiveX=true" />
```

But removing it doesn't change anything. More frustrating, sometimes it works fine and I can guarantee I have made no change since then.

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

2 weeks on this issue, I ask the question and I found the problem myself 15 minutes later. :(

The iFrame had a "frameset" and once loaded within the iFrame, was breaking the handling of the main frame. I solved my problem by targeting my links to the frameset's name after the first click and it is now working fine!